# (PL/)SQL View over 3 tables, username & password

Tags: sql, oracle, view, plsql, oracle-apex

I have 3 tables: personal_trainer, manager and member which all contain some other data and the valuable username, password.

Now the problem is, I want to login with these accounts, I already have a PL/SQL code for the custom authentication. But this is impossible? over 3 tables if I also want to assign a variable to check their priviliges.

I'm already quite far into my application and thus of that I want to create a view that will gather the usernames and passwords from the 3 tables. If possible I'd like to either create a variable within that view, or being able to track out of which table the data is coming.

How would I create this view and how can I get the information?

***Working with Oracle database***

Comment: Oracle Apex 4.x woops, deleted it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `Union all`

```
create or replace view all_passwords as
select 'personal_trainer' tbl_info, username, password
from personal_trainer

union all

select 'manager' tbl_info, username, password
from manager 

union all

select 'member' tbl_info, username, password
from member
```